# an iframe for multiple users

Tags: html, iframe, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to create a web page with the following :

Buttons and input fields etc. in the top half of the page that allow the user to define certain criteria, when the user clicks submit, the page calls some php code that writes an iframe referenced html file which is then shewn on the bottom part of the web page.

I think I understand how to do this for a web page referring to a single iframe document source but there may be more than one user running the page so how do I have the iframe pointing to the correct iframe source for each user?

Some web searching sugests that this is the kind of thing done with XMLHttpRequest, I'll have a look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your PHP code creates an HTML file and then loads it in an iframe.

You could have your PHP script output the HTML, then load the PHP script in your iframe directly. Now there is no way for another user to accidentally get the other users' output.

Comment: @Lasar I should have said I need the user to enter some information on the page before the php can run so they would need to be able to submit it not simply have the php run in the iframe.

Comment: Why is the data in an iframe anyway? Couldn't i just be part of the document itself? If not, you could either set the iframe's src to output.php?param1=value1&param2=value2&etc for all form fields. Or you could save the form submitted data in a session variable (`session_start(); $_SESSION['myFormData']=$formData`) that can then be read in the iframe php file (`session_start(); $data = $_SESSION['myFormData'];`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you want to do.. but if you have already existing database of users, make a new table with Iframe preferences... so when they click submit, the preferences will be saved to the database with the user_id.. so next time just check if the user has already chosen... if yes, get the preferences from database.. if not -> redirect him to do so.

I don't know if that's exactly what you want